# Why reordering takes place with two volatile variables?

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile, java-memory-model

I'm trying to investigate the behaviour of reordering in java environment(using JDK 9-ea+170) and found one thing that i can't explain for myself, so i will be glad to hear some notes about it. Here's an example:

```
public class Client {
    int x;
    int y;
    public void test() {
        x++;
        y++;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client c = new Client();
        while(c.y <= c.x) new Thread(() -> c.test()).start();
        System.out.println(c.x + " " + c.y);
    }
}
```

This program has a `test()` method which just increments x and y values. I'm creating new Threads and call this `test()` until some internal java optimizations are not changes an order of `x++; y++;` instructions(). This way i prove that reordering really takes place. And the program ends most of the time(which is expected).
 Now i've added volatile modifier to y:

```
public class Client {
    int x;
    volatile int y;
    public void test() {
        x++;
        y++;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client c = new Client();
        while(c.y <= c.x) new Thread(() -> c.test()).start();
        System.out.println(c.x + " " + c.y);
    }
}
```

This program never ends because volatile guarantees that all of the instructions before volatile will be flushed into the memory so `x++;` always executed before `y++;` and it's not possible to have y > x. This is also expected from my understanding. But after that i've added volatile to `int x;` too and now i can see reorderings again so program ends most of the time:

```
public class Client {
    volatile int x;
    volatile int y;
    public void test() {
        x++;
        y++;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client c = new Client();
        while(c.y <= c.x) new Thread(() -> c.test()).start();
        System.out.println(c.x + " " + c.y);
    }
}
```

Why reordering takes place here also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not evidence of reordering.  In fact, what is happening is a result of `++` on a `volatile` not being atomic.  For example, consider the following interleaving of operations by two threads (`A` and `B`) when updating one of the variables (`x`):

```
thread A: load x -> temp
thread B: load x -> temp
thread A: temp = temp + 1
thread B: temp = temp + 1
thread A: save temp -> x
thread B: save temp -> x
```

and if you work through those operations with that interleaving, you will see that you have lost a count on `x`.  That is sufficient for the `c.y <= c.x` to fail occasionally.

(The "lost count" behavior could also happen with `y` ... which explains why this experiment only fails some of the time.)

Comment: Could you please provide an example how it's possible that B > A?
 In the flow that you've described above an assignment to A happens before assignment to B.

Comment: 1) The variables are `x` and `y`.  `A` and `B` denote threads.  2) All that needs to happen is that you lose more counts on `x` than you do on `y`, and then `y <= x` will be `false`.

Comment: Thanks for update! Now it's a bit cleaner for me. Stephen, now i'm running the same code but with synchronized keyword on test(). It works ok when volatile is on y or on x and y but fails without volatile(which is expected) and fails when volatile only on x. Is it normal behaviour? Please explain if you know what's going on

Comment: Yes.  It is normal.  When you access a non-volatile variable without doing it within a mutex, you may see a stale value for that variable.